# Pressing the button element listview

Tags: android

I have a sheet with buttons. I assign an event handler to an element of the sheet. and when you get him the position. But I need to assign an event to a button that is in this element of the sheet. I do it in the adapter and it is pressed. but how do I determine which element of the sheet was pressed?

```
class RecordAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<RecordBean> recordBeans;
    Context ctx;

    public RecordAdapter(final Context ctx, ArrayList<RecordBean> recordBeans) {
        this.recordBeans =recordBeans;
        this.ctx=ctx;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return recordBeans.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recorditem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recordate);
            holder.from = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recordFrom);
            holder.to = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recordTo);
            holder.seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            holder.start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            holder.stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.date.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getDate());
        holder.from.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getFrom());
        holder.to.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getTo());
        holder.start.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnStart:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx,Uri.parse(recordBeans.get(3).getFile()));
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView date;
        TextView from;
        TextView to;
        SeekBar seekBar;
        Button start;
        Button stop;
    }
    }
}
```

instead `recordBeans.get(3).getFile()`  I want to write `recordBeans.get(itemPosition).getFile()`

Now I have the same setting to all buttons

Comment: Set your Button `onClickListner` as inner class and pass position in your `getView(.....)`

Comment: you have `position` variable in `getView(...)` method use it. better use anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this inside your `getView(...)` method itself

```
     holder.start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx,Uri.parse(recordBeans.get(position).getFile()));
                    mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });
```

same for `stop`.

```
     holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  mediaPlayer.stop();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Set you **RecordBean** data to start **Button** **Tag** and when you click appropriate start **Button** get value from **Tag** and use it as per your requirement.

```
class RecordAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    ArrayList<RecordBean> recordBeans;
    Context ctx;

    public RecordAdapter(final Context ctx, ArrayList<RecordBean> recordBeans) {
        this.recordBeans =recordBeans;
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return recordBeans.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.recorditem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recordate);
            holder.from = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recordFrom);
            holder.to = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recordTo);
            holder.seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            holder.start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            holder.stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.date.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getDate());
        holder.from.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getFrom());
        holder.to.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getTo());
        holder.start.setTag(recordBeans.get(position));
        holder.start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx,Uri.parse(((RecordBean) v.getTag()).getFile()));
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView date;
        TextView from;
        TextView to;
        SeekBar seekBar;
        Button start;
        Button stop;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! exactly the same answer but it is working!

Comment: @IP696,can you please approve and upvote ans if is useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    final int itemPosition = position;

    holder.start.setOnClickListenerOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx,Uri.parse(recordBeans.get(itemPosition ).getFile()));
                   mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    });
            holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop());
    }
    });
```